# Using aiohttp class based views without creating redundant endpoints

Tags: python, aiohttp

I am currently implementing an API using `aiohttp`. I am using class based views and I have a few endpoints with and without variable paths. When I try to combine the variable paths with the class based views I end up creating redundant endpoints. Below is some example code that describes my problem.

Let's say I want the following endpoints and methods:

```
GET api/users
DELETE api/users/{id}
```

I do his using the following code:

```
from aiohttp import web


class UserView(web.View):

    async def get(self):
        return web.json_response({"result": []})

    async def delete(self):
        user_id = self.request.match_info.get("id", None)
        return web.json_response({"result": f"User {user_id} was deleted"})


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_view("/users", UserView)
    app.router.add_view("/users/{id}", UserView)
    web.run_app(app)
```

My code creates the following endpoints and method combinations.

```
GET api/users
GET api/users{id}
DELETE api/users
DELETE api/users/{id}
```

As you can see, I don't need all of them. I there any way I can still use class based views and variable paths without ending up with redundant endpoint/method combinations?

Comment: I think it should be 2 different views, because aiohttp creates each endpoint for each path, so it's better to use one class based view for one path

Comment: Yep, that would be a solution, I do think its cleaner to have all the users stuff in one view though. But if that doesn't work I probably will have to use separate views. @YuriiKramarenko, what do you think would be a good naming convention for the two views?

Comment: `api/users -> UsersView` because looks like this url could be associated with many users, `api/users/{id} -> UserView` because it relates to concrete user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can do this by passing the view to the router's `get`, `post` ... methods!

```py
from aiohttp import web


class UserView(web.View):

    async def get(self):
        return web.json_response({"result": []})

    async def delete(self):
        user_id = self.request.match_info.get("id", None)
        return web.json_response({"result": f"User {user_id} was deleted"})


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = web.Application()
    app.router.get("/users", UserView)
    app.router.delete("/users/{id}", UserView)
    web.run_app(app)
```